# If I store more data in Redux Store or React Context, Will it slow down more efficiency?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

just like the title:
more data store, will more efficiency lost ?

little example:

there are two app with all same condition, function and environment except:
the A app store a list with length === 1
the B app store a list with length === 100000

will efficiency of B slower than A ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are going to do with all those 100000. Obviously, the global state with 100000 elements takes more memory and for most cases more time to operate with.